# Can someone confirm this Fourier series from example 3.5 in Alan V. Oppenheim's book?

Tags: integration, fourier-series, signal-processing

On page 193 the following example shows that $a₁ = 1/ π$

[image]
[image]
[image]

**But solving with this formula gives me $a₁ = 2/ π$**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oppenheim has published more than one book.

Comment: If you plan to continue participating at Math.SE, learning [to include math notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in your posts will smooth their reception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there's an error in the textbook and your derivation is correct.

---

The function $x(t)$ is defined as follows:

---

**(1)** $\quad x(t)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & |t|<T_1 \\
 0 & T_1<|t|<\frac{T}{2} \\
 x(|t|-T) & \text{True} \\
\end{array}\right.$

---

For $T=2 \pi$ and $T=4 T_1$ formula (1) above simplifies to formula (2) below with Fourier series illustrated in formula (3) below.

---

**(2)** $\quad x(t)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & | t| <\frac{\pi}{2} \\
 0 & \frac{\pi}{2}<|t|<\pi \\
 x(|t|-2 \pi) & \text{True} \\
\end{array}\right.$

**(3)** $\quad x(t)=\frac{1}{2}+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\ \sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{2 \sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{2}\right)}{\pi k} \cos (k t)$

---

The following table gives the first $10$ coefficients of the Fourier cos series defined in formula (3) above.

---

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \frac{2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{2}\right)}{\pi  k} \\
 1 & \frac{2}{\pi } \\
 2 & 0 \\
 3 & -\frac{2}{3 \pi } \\
 4 & 0 \\
 5 & \frac{2}{5 \pi } \\
 6 & 0 \\
 7 & -\frac{2}{7 \pi } \\
 8 & 0 \\
 9 & \frac{2}{9 \pi } \\
 10 & 0 \\
\end{array}$$

---

Figure (1) below illustrates formula (3) for $x(t)$ in orange overlaid on the reference function defined in formula (2) in blue where formula (3) is evaluated at $K=20$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (3) for x(t)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (3) for $x(t)$

Comment: I studied hard on this and find out that there's actually two types of FS. Trigonometric and Exponential Fourier Series. With both methods giving a different answers but there is a relation between both the answers [Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/signals_and_systems/fourier_series_types.htm).

Comment: @thenoobslayer Of course, since $e^{i x}=\cos (x)+i \sin (x)$.